# Doctrine query builber: a problem adding multiple conditions with andWhere

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a number of conditions:

```
if (!empty($requestData['year'])) {
                    $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->eq('dd.year', $requestData['year']);
}
if(!empty($requestData['month'])){
                    $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->eq('dd.month', $this->convertMonthStringToNumber($requestData['month']));
}
```

Which I am trying to add to the andWhere. I have found this solution:

```
$andX = $qb->expr()->andX();
$andX->addMultiple($conditions);
$qb->andWhere($andX);
```

But this throws me an error:

```
assert($lookahead !== null)
in [SERVER]\vendor\doctrine\orm\src\Query\Parser.php (line 2639)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `andWhere()` directly? Like `$qb->andWhere('dd.year = :year')->andWhere('dd.month = :month')`

Comment: Well, yes, I could, that's what I've done before, but I was exploring this way, which seems neater and workable if I need to loop through array values instead in the future... So would be good to know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$andX = $qb->expr()->andX(...$conditions);
$qb->andWhere($andX);
```